# what are actual formulas for glOrtho

Tags: opengl

Working with legacy project that used OpenGL and adapting it to OpenGL ES I stumbled upon this problem.
I have to implement  matrix stack use on my own and create some state machine and own implementation of glOrtho and glPerspective,  but some documentation are different, depending on which source I look.

Documentation on Kronos website is mangled and unusable. Documentation on Microsoft site

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/opengl/glortho?redirectedfrom=MSDN]

Another version, which matches also formulas in man pages and some books:

[image: https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/reisert/opengl/doc/glOrtho.html]

Experimentation with `glGelFloatv()` had shown that on Windows `glOrtho()` uses first version. Is it possible that other platforms use another? There were plenty problems with projection matrix in this code base and trying swapping out implementation aggravated either one or another, to the point that I get impression that sign actually changes under some conditions.
Which variant I should to follow? Does glOrtho contain some additional logic aside from multiplying existing matrix on new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only truth is the specification. From [OpenGL 2.1 API specification - 2.11.2 Matrices](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec21.pdf#page=60&zoom=100,134,374):

> `void Ortho( double l, double r, double b, double t, double n, double f );`
>
> describes a matrix that produces parallel projection. (l b − n)T and (r t − n)T specify the points on the near clipping plane that are mapped to the lower left and upper right corners of the window, respectively. f gives the distance from the eye to the far clipping plane. If l is equal to r, b is equal to t, or n is equal to f, the error INVALID VALUE results. The corresponding matrix is
>
> [image]

(The most recent [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification - 12.1 Fixed-Function Vertex Transformations](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.withchanges.pdf#page=528&zoom=100,168,730) says the same)

Comment: duh, they moved it pdf which is unopenable\unsearchable from secure network. It actually looks like either MESA or ATI X driver don't follow that strictly. ANd text version on that site  lacks minuses!

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The didn't move in in a PDF. The specification is provided in pdf format since ever. See [OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php)

Comment: published specification predates pdf existence in web. it were text pages, like man pages, they still exist but browser misrepresent them.  That one is a late thing.

Comment: xhtml refpages, predates wiki  by half of decade, but I accept your version *nod*

Comment: The forumla for `glOrtho` was first specified in the [OpenGL 1.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec10.pdf) and unchanged ever since. Actually, the formula is taken over from IrisGL's `ortho` command  which originated at SGI sometime during the 80s, which also introduced the coordinate frame conventions OpenGL later used.